# Recreate cloudflare-like analytics on Google DNS

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I need to recreate Cloudflare-like visitor analytics (unique monthly visitors and countries at least) using only data provided by GCP DNS. I couldn't find any writeups on how to do this without using the google analytics script.

Are there any pointers on how to do this without migrating the domain to cloudflare?

Comment: Do not try to use DNS for that task. Clients cache DNS responses which would bias your measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting Mr. @JohnHanley comment as answer to help other users understand this query. “Do not try to use DNS for that task. Clients cache DNS responses which would bias your measurements.”

In addition, you can enable cloud logging upon creation of your Cloud dns or [Enable existing Cloud DNS’s logs](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/monitoring?_gl=1*7f0cee*_ga*MTkzNDk0MjQyMS4xNjkwOTE0NjA0*_ga_WH2QY8WWF5*MTY5MTAxNDU2My4zLjAuMTY5MTAxNTA4NC4wLjAuMA..&_ga=2.77534549.-1934942421.1690914604#enabling_and_disabling_logging_for_managed_public_zones). You can also check [Cloud DNS Logging](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/monitoring#using_logging) on what DNS logging tracks.